# I want to use innerHTML in javascript but it's not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to pass an html line with an id coming from javascript, I used innerHTML but I can't get it to work, if I use a simple string it works

```js
function passid(id){
   var lengthOfName = id
   document.getElementById('output').innerTEXT = "<input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="'lengthOfName'">";
    
};
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: `innerTEXT -> innerText` plus you need to escape those quotes in between the starting and ending quotes.

Comment: also, you're assigning a rather broken value, since you're not escaping any of those inner quotes. Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) if you want a string with lots of quotes in it. But more than that: put your script in its own file like `script.js` and then load that with `<script src="script.js" async defer></script>` in the head of your document, so that it runs _after_ the document has been built up and can be queried for elements.

Answer (score 0):

you should use backticks and innerHTML.

```
    function passid(id){
      var lengthOfName = id
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `
      <input type="text" id="test" name="test" value=${lengthOfName}>`;
   };
```

Comment: Safer to quote the value also

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is some small fixes

```
function passid(id){
   var lengthOfName = id
   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `<input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="${lengthOfName}">`;
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, you are using innerTEXT with a string of HTML. This will not parse the HTML in your string and input element to the DOM.

Depending on how your are 'passing your id using javascript', you may need to defer the code as suggested in one of the comments. But you can use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) with 'afterbegin' as the placement of the HTML string. Also I would use template literals and encase your variable dollar sign and curly brackets like so =>  `${id}`.

*See my example, if this is not what you are looking for please let me know and I will properly address my answer.*

```js
let id = "myid";

function passid(id){
   let el = document.getElementById('output');
   let str = `<input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="${id}">`;  
   el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', str);
};

passid(id);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```